# where do we fit feasibility study and analysis in SDLC

Tags: sdlc

In general the SDLC has the following phase

requirement gathering 
design 
coding
testing 
deployment

but in the above SDLC , where do I fit the below phases ( i know it is around requirement gathering and desing phase)

1) feasibility study

strategic feasibility study ( what we do in this phase?)
   technical feasiblility study( what we do in this phase?)

2) Analysis( what we do in this phase ? how is it different from feasibility study ?)

3) modeling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I would say a feasibility study (and proof of concept) happen during requirements gathering and before general design.  The purpose is to identify issues that maybe difficult or impossible to implement (technologically, cost, time, etc.), create a subset or manageable chunk of those issues and implement them in a PoC.
2. Analysis is your more typical phase where you take your requirements and decide what technologies might serve to help realize them.  You do things like platform selection, vendor analyses and things of that nature.  This is different from a feasibility study in that you're not trying to prove that something is possible, but you're trying to identify implementation decisions you need to make to realize the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I'm very sure they have provided some textbook for your course in your institute. If they haven't please try reading [Roger S. Pressman's](http://www.rspa.com/) ["Software Engineering: A Practitioner's Approach"](http://books.google.com.sg/books?id=metaHQAACAAJ&dq=Roger+S+Pressman&source=an&hl=en&ei=5WJdSvyuCJOMkAWnmqnhDA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=8). It is really great and insightful book.

Answer (score 0):

I have to design a feasibility study tool, what are the criterias I have to take in to consideratios. Which part of RE is most important to perform feasibility study.